# Is there a recipe for a Kosher for Passover beer or ale?

Tags: specialty-beers, ale, home-brewing

I'm looking to do a home brew of a Kosher for Passover beer. Is there a recipe I can follow?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a company that's trying it:

> …
> According to Chabad.org, beer is '"chametz." What's chametz? According to the site, it's "any food product made from **wheat, barley, rye, oats or spelt** that has come into contact with water and been allowed to ferment and rise." Aka, considering it is made from wheat and barley, beer is not Passover approved. But! All hope isn't lost — there are now "beers" on the market that are permitted on the Passover table.
>
> An Israeli brewing company called Meadan Craft Brewing has created a beer that's totally kosher for Passover. How? Well, as you know, standard beer is chametz, meaning, it's made with ingredients that need to rise which makes it against Passover law. But this special beer is made with dates. Not only that, but it's gluten-free, too.
> …
> — [Is Beer Kosher For Passover? Here's What You Need To Know About This Popular Drink](https://www.bustle.com/p/is-beer-kosher-for-passover-heres-what-you-need-to-know-about-this-popular-drink-49548)

But how you can call something made from fruit "beer", when it's obviously "wine", I don't know.

You might consider corn, since it isn't one of the proscribed grains.

But again, there's still the problem of the yeast.

And of course anyone involved in the process up until it's bottled must be a Sabbath-observing male.

Comment: Re. your last sentence; might you be confusing this with the production of **wine**?

Comment: @Oliver, yes.  I assumed that whatever is required for wine to be kosher for Passover would apply to other fermented beverages too.

Answer (score 0):

A hopped apple cider that's fermented fairly dry is a great Kosher for Passover beer substitute.

Like this one - [www.passoverbeer.com](http://www.passoverbeer.com)

And here is homebrew information:

https://byo.com/article/hopped-cider/